# How to execute more than one .sql files in sql server 2008 using powershell?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, powershell

I have more than 100 .sql files to execute on sql server 2008 R2.But i don't want to do it manually. So, i googled about the possible solutions and found that i can use powershell to execute these scripts but i never used powershell before. I found below mentioned command-

`Get-ChildItem ".\Stored Procedures\*.sql" | ForEach-Object { sqlcmd -S ServerName -d DatabaseName -E -i $_.FullName }`

I replaced it with my parameters-

`Get-ChildItem "C:\tables\*.sql" | ForEach-Object { sqlcmd -S 10.50.102.124 -d falhpdv1stage -E -i $_.FullName }`

After executing this command, i refreshed my database but i am not able to see the newly executed tables? Am i missing something?

Comment: Have you checked that one of the commands works?  The problem could be anything from syntax errors in the SQL files to authentication problems on your machine to mistyping the IP address.

Comment: Please write a log file so you know Errors. add this code at the end of the line  `| >> execSp.log`

Comment: Why don't you convert them to a single stored procedure?

Comment: What happens when you run just one one of the scripts with sqlcmd? Like `sqlcmd -S 10.50.102.124 -d falhpdv1stage -E -i c:\tables\newTable.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have Management Studio installed on the computer where you're running the scripts:

```
add-pssnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100;
Get-ChildItem "C:\tables\*.sql" | ForEach-Object { invoke-sqlcmd -serverinstance 10.50.102.124 -database falhpdv1stage  -inputfile $_.FullName }
```

This also assumes that everything else is correct - correctly-written queries, appropriate permissions on the database, correct server IP & database name, etc.

Comment: I am able to execute the command in one environment but not able to open powershell in other environment(in this windows authentication is used but in the previous one sql server authentication is used).

Comment: You can pass the `-username` and `-password` parameters to invoke-sqlcmd to use SQL authentication. Any current Windows server should have PowerShell installed & available.